# objectContext life scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Today I came across in an issue that I can't explain exactly the reason, so I think the better is to share it via stackoverflow.

Well, I have an mvc 3 application with .net entities and I tried to insert in db a huge string and this produced a sqlExeepton "string or binary data would be truncated". Ok up to here, I will fix it later :).

After this issue, I tried to update the same entity by a single value (in fact I increased a counter) and got again the same exception. That socked be a bit.

If I dispose the objectContext at the end of each method or I if create a new objectContext at the start of each method the problem will be solved.

What I can not understand is how does the objectContext reacts if it get initialized in the class instead of a method

```
public class MyController : BaseController {

    private static EFUnitOfWork efUnitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork();
    Products_Repository productsRepos = new Products_Repository(new EFRepository<Products>(), efUnitOfWork); 
..
//methods
..
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> how does the objectContext reacts if it get initialized in the class?

You will have one instance which lives as long as your controller class lives. And that will match the lifetime of one http request and thats the recommended lifetime when coding web apps.

So you get a fresh context for every single request and have not to bother with some old state  stored in an old context object.

Comment: I agree that this is the recommended lifetime. As you said it lives for every single http request. In my understanding, if I call the controller A then it get initialized. If I call the controller B, then the controller A disposed and the controller B get initialized. If this is correct, then why am I getting the exception despite that the controller A get disposed and re initialized?

Comment: What do you mean with *calling controller B*? The controller classes are instantiated and the action methods are called normally by the framework and not by yourself. You should ensure, that you use jsut one instance of your datacontext per request. I recommend using a DI container and inject the instance in the constructor of your (base) controller class.

Comment: I mean that If I access let's say the controllerA/index and after this the controllerB/index, then controllerA will be disposed and the controllerB will be initialized again. I assume that I have understood them in a wrong way. By the way I will try to implement the DI

Comment: Yes, but that involve two requests and on the controllerB/Index call you should get a new datacontext.

Comment: Yes that's the point. The new datacontext shouldn't raise the same exception.